# Can't get the Object Array into Controller Function called from the Aura Component <ui:InputNumber>

Tags: arrays, object, controller, salesforce-lightning

Thank you, everyone, for helping me!
I am just stuck I don't know if this was the issue with Salesforce or

I am doing something wrong!!!

Here  is the scenario I have enabled inline editing on the card and when the user changes the value of the Quantity, the component call the JS Controller function

It didn't get the List which I have passed as a Parameter its Nothing output is attached below,

**Interesting Fact**

1. But I called the same function from somewhere else like make a 
   checkbox and on the change called the same, I get the list of Array 
   passed as Parameter
2. I didn't get the List when I called it from the 
   other than that I get all the values using component.get()

**Aura Component Attributes**

```
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Object" required="true"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="title" type="String" required="true"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="bid" type="Object[]" required="true"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="box1" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="categoriesSum" type="Object" required="true"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="quantityEditMode" type="boolean" default="false"></aura:attribute>
```

**Component Code Calling with InputNumber Not working**

```
   <ui:inputNumber class="slds-input " labelClass="slds-form- 
   element__label slds-form-element__label_edit slds-no-flex" 
   change ="{!c.onQuantityChange}" 
   required="true" value=" 
   {!v.item.Quantity__c}" />
```

**Component Code Calling with CheckBox Working**

```
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox1" value="v2" change="{!c.onQuantityChange}"/>
```

**JS Controller**

```
  onQuantityChange : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('----Item----'+component.get('v.item')); 
    console.log('----title---'+ component.get('v.title'));
    console.log('----Bid---'+ component.get('v.bid'));
    console.log('----Box---'+ component.get('v.box1'));
    console.log('---categoriesSum--component.get('v.categoriesSum'));
    console.log('----quantityEditMode---'+ component.get('v.quantityEditMode'));

   }
```

**Output with InputNumber**
[image]

**Ouputput with Checkbox**
[image]

if you need more explanation please let me know I m stuck here for almost 7 hours and yes I have also tried the helper class it's the same scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly change the value of a field on the object using

```
value=" 
   {!v.item.Quantity__c}"
```

Instead try saving it in an attribute like v2 (you have done that on the checkbox)

The change from the ui:inputNumber will then make it to the controller.

Basically this:

```
<aura:attribute name="v2" type="Integer"/>
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input " labelClass="slds-form- 
   element__label slds-form-element__label_edit slds-no-flex" 
   change ="{!c.onQuantityChange}" 
   required="true" value=" 
   {!v.v2}" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Aditiya the  main problem was I was not getting the list, because in the panel when called I was not sending the list

Comment: So I was sending the list in the other panel's but I was not sending the list from the Revised bid Panel, so when I called my function with another panel I got the list, but when I call the same function from the revised panel it's NULL

Comment: @Malik - Were you able to solve it? I am not sure what you mean by panel. Maybe share some code which I can look at?

Comment: my problem is resolved, thank you very much for helping me, if you want to see the solution I will share it with you no worries